# How to propagate configuration changes to all pods in a microservice architecture deployed on Kubernetes ? Inter pod communication Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I'm working on a microservice architecture deployed on Kubernetes where each service comprises multiple pods. I encounter an issue when attempting to propagate configuration changes across all pods simultaneously.

Currently, when I invoke an API endpoint in a service to apply configuration changes, only the pod handling that specific request undergoes the update. However, this leaves other pods within the service unaffected, resulting in inconsistency across the deployment.

What would be the best approach to ensure that configuration changes are applied uniformly across all pods within a service? Are there Kubernetes-native mechanisms or best practices to achieve this?

Note that, the number of pods is not constant, and pods can be deleted or created dynamically. Additionally, pod names are not constant.

Comment: The whole point with "microservices" is that they should NOT be _tightly coupled_, e.g. they should not depend on "propagate configuration changes across all pods simultaneously" - they MUST be designed the opposite way, they should be Independently deployable.

Comment: are you talking about "configuration" of some kubernetes thing or is that "configuration" related to your application? if it's related to your application, maybe you can use a centralized config service, where services ask it values of a key (somewhat like https://openfeature.dev does)

Comment: If you can push configuration changes using a Kubernetes-level mechanism like a ConfigMap, every replica will see them more or less simultaneously.  You probably won't be able to change that using external API calls to your application, though.